# Спроектировать БД

Tags: база-данных, oracle, проектирование

Здравствуйте, в качестве курсового проекта по БД выбрал «Учёт доходов/расходов личного бюджета». Трудности возникли с проектированием базы данных.

[image: Моя база данных]

Постараюсь объяснить что тут к чему (в будущем будет web приложение на Java).

- Есть `user` — пользователь, и информация о нем.
- К пользователю привязан аккаунт, у которого есть столбец-баланс, тип и что-то вроде флаг(админ это или нет).
- В отдельную таблицу я вынес бюджет, которым обладает владелец аккаунта. тут у нас сумма, которая имеется, помесячный бюджет `title` — это оповещение куда или откуда потратились/пришли деньги.

А дальше то, что я не могу с этим увязать: таблица `services_section` — это таблица услуг, на что мы потратили деньги т.е. продукты, развлечения, налоги. А `type_service` — это уже конкретнее, т.е. если `service_section` выдаст только тип услуги, например — продукты, то `type_service` — выдаст, например, банан.

Это мой первый опыт в проектировании БД и я логику где-то нарушаю, а где, не пойму.

Спасибо.

Comment: добавьте описание каждой таблицы.

Comment: Наверное, уже поздно, но можете объяснить в чем Вы видите проблему? Вы вроде начали `А дальше то, что я не могу с этим увязать...`, но следом идет описание таблиц, а что с ними не так не сказано. Кроме описания таблиц нужно указать кратность отношений.